# Magento 2 - Should I always copy the whole layout file into my theme and make my changes?

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.3.4

I have to modify the layout of the **catalog_product_view.xml**.

Should I copy the whole file into my theme and then make my changes or should I create the file **catalog_product_view.xml** in my theme and make changes by referencing blocks and containers?

In my opinion it would be better to copy the whole layout file, because if a magento update is getting released, then it might break the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme is extending either Magento\blank or Magento\luma I think it's fairly safe to just include the updates as these don't seem to be updated much.

If it's extending another 3rd party theme you'd probably be best making that judgement yourself.

Of course if you want to keep the layout from being affected from as few changes as possible your theme should have no parent. 
In this case you would want to copy the whole file most likely.

Comment: But even if I copy the whole parent file and new changes are being made in these parent files by updates, then these changes are loaded from the parent. So it looks like there is no safe way if you extend a parent... you can't tell magento to only load your layout file and ignore the original layout

Comment: That's true but for the most part this is considered when if/when they update a theme. I've not had major issues with magento updates affecting my layouts on many sites, but as you said - it can happen..

Comment: You can also completly override a layout: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html

This will prevent that any future magento updates will have any effect